# Get to a specific inode, in a ext2 image (C)

Tags: c, filesystems, inode, ext2

I want to get to a specifIC inode (using its number), within an ext2 image, using the C language. I'm traying to do this by opening the ext2 image with the open() syscall, and then traverse it using lseek() with the right offsets, until I get to the inode. Is this correct? Or am I doing something wrong? I'm a little confused whether using open() is correct, or there is more appropriate functions to do this.

```
int fd = open("ext2fs.img", O_RDONLY);
assert(fd != -1);


off_t startPosition = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
assert(startPosition != -1);
```

Should I just add offsets to startPosition until I get to the inodes? But how can I search for a specific inode?

**UPDATED (to be more specific)**

I already have the layout of the ext2 file system (http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html), this gives me everything (all the offsets) important I need. And I need to create a C program to manipulate the metadata and data. Like removing and copying files, for example.

I know what to do, but I'm having trouble implementing it.

For example: To test if I know what I'm doing, I'm trying to read the number of free inodes in an ext2 disk image my professor provided, doing this:

```
#define SUPER_BLOCK 1024

int main()
{
    int freeInodes;

    int fd = open("path.img", O_RDONLY);
    off_t startPosition = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);

    lseek(fd, startPosition + SUPER_BLOCK + 16, SEEK_CUR);
    read(fd, freeInodes, 4);
    printf("Number of free inodes: %d", freeInodes);
}
```

The output I receive is: "Number of free inodes: 32767"

Am I interpreting the data I got from read() correctly? I have no idea if this value received is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real use case for accessing by inode, except to circumvent file system security.
In Linux, `debugfs` allows you to do that.  If you think it is an absolute requirement try the source code for debugfs.

Consider using the stat() call from file tree walk (ftw()/nftw() ) as a callback,  or use stat() + scandir() directly for faster coding.  Either will allow you to get all inodes of files you have permissions to stat.  And open or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing a raw read on the file system image, something similar to what is done in `fsck.ext{2,3,4}`. However, this would require one to extensive knowledge the ext{2,3,4} layout, on-disk structures and a understanding of the magic numbers (offset on the disk which point to bitmaps / other metadata) to determine where the inode bitmaps start on the disk.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do! I already have the layout of the ext2 file system (http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html), this gives me everything (all the offsets) important I need. And I need to create a C program to manipulate the metadata and data.

I already know what to do, but I'm having trouble implementing it. I'm going to update the original post.

Comment: hello @MiguelPéres I am trying to do the same thing... did you make any progress?

Comment: Sorry @Zibri, I ended using Python, never figured it out. And it's been a long time, so I don't remember how I did it. If you make any progress please come back to share you result!

Comment: No problem, I figured it out and I made a small C program to edit a single inode :D